# Where is "Nearest neighbour analysis" tool in pyqgis documentation?

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have a group of point features for which I want to run the Nearest neighbour analysis using python. The problem is that I cannot find that function in the documentation.

The closest I got was:
https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/other/QgsSpatialIndex.html?highlight=nearest#qgis.core.QgsSpatialIndex.nearestNeighbor

However, this seems to work on a point level? I want to run the analysis per feature like you would do using Vector Analysis->Nearest neighbour analysis.

Could someone pin me this in the documentation, or suggest an alternative?

Comment: With QGIS 3.6, create a processing model using Nearest neighbour analysis in Vector Analysis processing tools section, save it and under QGIS, export it (right click) to python.